# Exchange data between same app on different devices

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have developed a iOS app, now I want to exchange data between two devices( it can be android or iOS) for same app.

Is it possible to do, with or without Internet connection?

Sharing ideas will help me a lot...

**Please help and thanks in advance....**

Comment: It's possible. With and without internet. Ask more specific question please.

Comment: Can you please share your idea how?

Comment: You need a server to exchange data with internet. Without internet – you need to implement exchanging over WiFi, bluetooth, etc. It is too broad question still.

Answer (score 0):

THe simplies way to do that is by using backend substitution frameworkds, such as Parse. With it you access your data as from database on each device. Parse is shuttong down now, but you can setup your own server.